# Algorithm for making straight lines out of bumpy pixels

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, signal-processing

**The Problem**:

I have an image that I downloaded from google's static map api. I use this image to basically create a "magic wand" type feature where a user clicks. For those interested I am using the graph cut algorithm to find the shape that the user clicked. I then find all the points that represent the border of this shape (borderPoints) using contour tracing.

**My Goal**:

Straighten out the lines (if possible) and minimize the amount of borderPoints (as much as possible). My current use case are the roofs of houses so in the majority of cases I would hope that I could find the corners and just use those as the borderPoints instead of all the varying points in between. But I am having trouble figuring out how to find those corners because of the bumpy pixel lines.

**My Attempts at a Solution**:

One simple technique is to loop over the points checking the point before, the current point, and the point after. If the point before and the point after have the same x or the same y then the current point can be removed. This trims the number of points down a little but not as much as I would like.

I also tried looking at the before and after point to see if the current point could be removed if it wasn't within a certain slope range but had little success because occasionally a key corner point was removed because the image was kind of fuzzy and the corner had slightly rounded points.

**My Question**:

Are there any algorithms for doing this type of thing? If so, what is it (they) called? If not, any thoughts on how to progamatically approach this problem?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer–Douglas–Peucker_algorithm

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will check it out and report how it went.

Comment: @MartinBeckett This was exactly what I needed. You should answer the question instead of commenting so I can mark it as the answer :). Otherwise I will mark the other person who answered it after you. Thanks again!

Comment: it's a great algorithm and everybody ends up re-inventing it whenever they need to approximate a line !

Comment: @MartinBeckett Are you going to create an answer for this? I am not trying to be annoying, I just want to make sure you get the points since you were the first to answer. If you don't care I will just upvote your comment and mark job's answer.

Comment: I only had time to make a quick suggestions about peucker algorithm so I didn't write an answer. I don't really care about points.

Comment: Sounds good. You definitely pointed me in the right direction though. It works awesome for what I am doing. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds similar to the [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm). You may be able to do better by exploiting the fact that all your points lie on a grid.

Comment: I wrote an answer with a little animation of the Douglas-Peucker algorithm if you are interested... http://stackoverflow.com/a/36937976/2836621

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like you are looking for a polynomial approximation of degree 1.

For a quick answer to your question, you may want to read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_regression. The Numerical example section shows you concretely how the equation for your line can be computed.

Polynomial approximations allow you to approach a function, curve, group of point, however you want to call it with a polynomial function of the form an.x^n + ... + a1.x^1 + a0

In your case, you want a line, so you want a function a1.x + a0 where a1 and a0 will be calculated to minimize the error with the set of points you have.

There are various ways of computing your error (called a norm) and minimizing it.  You may be interested for example in finding the line that minimizes the distance to any of the points you have (minimizing the max), or in minimizing the distance to the set of points as a whole (minimizing the sum of absolute differences, or the sum of squares of differences, etc.)

In terms of algorithms, you may want to look at Chebyshev approximations and Remez algorithms specifically.  All of these solve the approximation of a function with a polynomial of any degree but in your case you will only care about degree 1.

Comment: I will check this out too, when I get a chance and report back. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Sure. If you don't have much time for this, the formula given to compute beta and alpha in  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_regression will work just fine for you.

Comment: The Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm worked so good I didn't try this out. Still thanks for the response.

Comment: No worries.  I didn't know about this algorithm myself and it does indeed seem to get you closer to what you were after.